# Update unrelated field when clicking Angular checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-change

I have a list of checkboxes for people, and I need to trigger an event that will display information about each person selected in another area of the view.  I am getting the event to run in my controller and updating the array of staff information.  However, the view is not updated with this information.  I think this is probably some kind of scope issue, but cannot find anything that works. I have tried adding a $watch, my code seems to think that is already running.  I have also tried adding a directive, but nothing in there seems to make this work any better.  I am very, very new to Angular and do not know where to look for help on this.

My view includes the following:

```
<div data-ng-controller="staffController as staffCtrl" id="providerList" class="scrollDiv">
    <fieldset>
        <p data-ng-repeat="person in staffCtrl.persons">
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedPersons" value="{{ physician.StaffNumber }}" data-ng-model="person.isSelected"
               data-ng-checked="isSelected(person.StaffNumber)" data-ng-change="staffCtrl.toggleSelection(person.StaffNumber)" />
            {{ person.LastName }}, {{ person.FirstName }}<br />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-ng-controller="staffController as staffCtrl">
    # of items: <span data-ng-bind="staffCtrl.infoList.length"></span>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="info in staffCtrl.infoList">
           <span data-ng-bind="info.staffInfoItem1"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My controller includes the following:

```
function getStaffInfo(staffId, date) {
    staffService.getStaffInfoById(staffId)
        .then(success)
        .catch(failed);
    function success(data) {
        if (!self.infoList.length > 0) {
           self.infoList = [];
        }
        var staffItems = { staffId: staffNumber, info: data };
        self.infoList.push(staffItems);
    }
    function failed(err) {
        self.errorMessage = err;
    }
}
self.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(staffId) {
    var idx = self.selectedStaff.indexOf(staffId);

    // is currently selected
    if (idx >= 0) {
        self.selectedStaff.splice(idx, 1);
        removeInfoForStaff(staffId);
    } else {
        self.selectedStaff.push(staffId);
        getStaffInfo(staffId);
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, there are two main problems. One in the template, and one in the controller logic.

Your template is the following :

```
<div data-ng-controller="staffController as staffCtrl" id="providerList" class="scrollDiv">
    <!-- ngRepeat where you select the persons -->
</div>
<div data-ng-controller="staffController as staffCtrl">
    <!-- ngRepeat where you show persons info -->
</div>
```

Here, you declared twice the controller, therefore, **you have two instances of it**. When you select the persons, you are storing the info in the data structures of the first instance. But the part of the view that displays the infos is working with other instances of the data structures, that are undefined or empty. The controller should be declared on a parent element of the two divs.

The second mistake is the following :

```
if (!self.infoList.length > 0) {
    self.infoList = [];
}
```

You probably meant :

```
if (!self.infoList) {
    self.infoList = [];
}
```

which could be rewrited as :

```
self.infoList = self.infoList || [];
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  I had it that way because different parts of the page use different controllers.  Two sections happen to use the same controller, but are separated by a section using a different controller.  Is it possible to just initialize 2 controllers all at once on a <div>?

Comment: Nope, seems that only the first is instantiated : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/mypvmugm/1/). But actually that does not make much sense to have two different controllers to control the exact same part of the view. The `staffController` has to wrap the select list and the display list, and there is absolutely no problem to nest the second controller, that is controlling a part of the view between the select list and the display list.